# Deleting message after using sendirect() on it in omnetpp

Tags: omnet++

In my project I have the following code snippet

```
if(strcmp(msg->getName(),"failedAck") == 0 || ......)
{
    msg->removeControlInfo();
    msg->setControlInfo(info);
    recvControls++;
    sendDirect(msg, table, "ackIn");
}
```

Essentially the a message arrives at its final destination (lets call it A*), and if it is a type of specified messages, it is sent to another module (B*) which uses the information it carries to perform an operation.

The problem I am having is that after sending the message to the other B*, I delete the message after I am done using it. However, it still appears as part of A* when I look in the inspector. And when I try and delete the message in A* I get an error message saying can't delete the message because it is currently scheduled. 
I can't figure out why this happens, Does this mean that sendDirect() does not change the ownership of the message (contrary to the manual)?

Help in this matter will be greatly appreciated, currently dealing with memory management issues in my simulation, and this is a part of it.

Comment: Are you sure that you see **the same** message in the inspector? Could you show code where you delete it after using? Is `table` a pointer to the another module?

Comment: Could you elaborate, where you delete the message in A*?

Comment: Are you sure that you are deleting the same message? You get the error that the message is scheduled because it is in the FES.

Comment: @JerzyD table is a pointer to another module, you need to provide that when using senddirect(). And I am sure its the same object it couldn't be anything else, usually when you send a message it changes ownership and you wouldn't see it under the object in the inspector.

Comment: @Michael I only delete the message in B*(using delete(msg).I don't do anything else,like pass it to another module or store it) because that's the final destination of the message, it doesn't make sense to delete the message before sending(obviously) and when I try to delete it after sending it gives me the error.

Comment: Really not sure without a look at the source code.
Usually, handleMessage is called, a new packet is created or casted from the msg that was handed over to handleMessage and this new message is transferred via sendDirect to another node/module. When the newly created packet arrived at is final destination, it is again (usually) casted and checked and deleted if not needed anymore. If that's what you do, I don't know why either the packet is still scheduled (maybe you didn't created a new packet to be sent via sendDirect?) or why there are still packets left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to withdraw this question and say thanks to everyone who looked at it. I just recently discovered that the items were being deleted when they were supposed to be. however, i had forgotten that i was making a clone of the object for other uses, that why it was showing up in the inspector. My apologies.